# Using/compiling Foundation SASS on live WordPress server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

so far I've used extensively LESS and BootStrap for many of my sites. However, I decided to start using Zurb Foundation as it seem more powerful, especially with the latest release (5).

With LESS, what I have always done was installing `WP-Less`, a plugin that uses phpLess library to compile `.less` stylesheets by looking at whatever `.less` file was enqueued using `wp_enqueue_style()` function within my WordPress theme. So if I made any editing on my main `.less` file and its dependanciens/inclusions, etc. and updloaded it on my server, WP-Less would notice that and recompile for me a new `.css` stylesheet, which is served to the end users. Magic!

I understood that Foundation is based on SASS and Compass. But these require ruby to run? Is there any equivalent of WP-Less for Foundation? Like, I enqueue `.sass` stylesheet and I have a library compiling for me the resulting `.css` if there's an update? So I can just do my edits locally, upload to the server and have my final stylesheet(s) recompiled automagically?

Sorry if I made any stupid assumptions, but this is how I had been working with LESS and BootStrap and it was rather efficient to me.

Thank you

Comment: ps yes I'm aware that I might compile my stylesheets locally by installing ruby and compass, then upload the compiled css to server - I guess with PhpStorm this would be easy to do, but I was still wondering if I could do it server-side, I'm used to it

Comment: Did you search for a WP-Sass type plugin? Otherwise, if you *really* want to be compiling SASS on your live server, you can install the Sass toolchain there.

Comment: the only I've found is WPLess but requires Ruby and I'm not sure if WPEngine, my host, supports it. I've also just discovered that WP 3.8 will include SASS into core using grunt-sass, but I'm uncertain if it will be for wp-admin only or if the new feature will grant the ability to theme developers to do what I described above

Comment: Then why don't you ask WP Engine what they support? They answer emails very quickly. Also, are you sure you Googled for WP and SASS?

Comment: sorry there's a mistake in my previous comment - the plugin is "WordLess" and not "WPLess" (the Less php processor for WP). I've inquired WP Engine at this point, but I'd doubt they'd support Ruby. Also, Wordless I'm not sure until which point will be supported. I'd rather go for any core-supported solution, I'm trying to understand if what is pushed inside WP 3.8 Core can work for template development too.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wp-sass https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-sass? I haven't tried the latest version, but I got it working locally for testing with Foundation 4.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that one although I was hoping in something as simple and straightforward as WP-Less, without introducing new functions in theme - anyway I've inquired my host - WPEngine - they say they don't currently support Ruby but they added that if SASS/SCSS is becoming part of the core in 3.8 they'll definitely do something about it - thanks

Comment: Great to hear that WPEngine will do something about it if SCSS becomes part of 3.8 and it looks like it will http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22862#comment:76 using grunt-sass that doesn't depend on Ruby.

Comment: There's one thing that is not clear to me though. Yes SASS/SCSS made it to core. But how us theme developers will be supposed to use it? just use wp_enqueue_stylesheet? I did not find any documentation yet on this

Comment: From the looks I'd say they use the Gruntfile in trunk http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/26145/trunk/Gruntfile.js and generate the CSS for each release and don't process SCSS using PHP.

Comment: so it means nothing to theme developers? or is there a way to process SCSS using js also for frontend?

Comment: You can't use the Gruntfile directly, but you could install grunt or yeoman.io and use grunt-sass just as core does to create the files before you deploy your theme.